# Pseudo readonly property on with serialization

Tags: c#, properties, readonly, xmlserializer

How bad is something like:

```
public class Test
{
    private string pKey = null;
    public string Key { 
        get { return pKey; } 
        set { if (pKey==null) pKey=value;} 
    }
}
```

This would allow me to use `XMLSerializer` with the class and make sure that `Key` can't be changed after being initially set.

Comment: Is pKey supposed to be private?

Comment: Ops, yes, pKey is supposed to be private. What I really wanted was something like `public string Key { get; private set; }`, but it is not allowed with XmlSerializer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree that my initial idea was bad.

I now know that there is no way to make this using the standard XML Serializer. 'ssg' suggestion won't be serialized because it doesn't have a public setter.

The only choices here are implementing the `IXmlSerializable`, or using another serialization method, like `DataContractSerializer`. The problem with the former is that every derivate of the class would also have to implement `IXmlSerializable`; the problem with the latter is that you can't use attributes or have much control over the generated XML.

Answer (score 0):

Bad, consider:

```
test.pKey = null;
test.Key = 'my new key';
```

I've managed to circumvent your protection (obviously you could add a `null` check to the set method to fix this issue).

The same problem could occur if the deserialized object had a `null` key, the key could still be set the first time it was accessed... It seems like if you need this sort of protection, you should probably look at another way of getting it.

The `XMLSerializer` places restrictions on the classes you use with it and by trying to work around those restrictions, you’re likely to cause confusion.  If you are a one-man shop and you are the only person that looks at the code, this may be less of an issue (at least until you step away from the code for a coupld of months), however in a multi-developer environment the behaviour of your class is likely to cause confusion.  For example, you’re hiding the assignment not working by not throwing an exception, so assignment operations would compile and run, but, not update the object and not throw an exception to indicate the failure (which could lead to some hard to track down bugs).

Comment: This shouln'd happen and I could throw an exception if an attempt to set Key with a null value happened (in my code that would qualify as an error so I'm okay with it).

Comment: You can replace the null exception with an _isSetted boolean field by each property. if that becomes a problem for you.